# How to create a hexagonal heat map using matplotlib(or other lib/tool)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-mining

I have a 2D Array, which contains the heatness of each unit.
It is easy to draw a 2D heatmap with square unit, but how can I draw one with hexagon.

---

Why I need this?
SOM(a learning algrithomn) outputs a hexagonal neuron network. I can get a distance map(U-Matrix, 2D matrix) from the trained model.

---

The `hexbin` funtion in matpyplot or `jointplot(kind="hex")` in seaborn only counts the frequency of each point. The input param is `x` and `y`. But what I have is a **2D Array** with weights(or say, color depth, which I want to paint).

---

Example, this image is from https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/73534694, I don't konw how to implement it
[image: example, I don't konw how he implements it]

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add a link to the source of the example above with the ACS features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to supply the grid coordinates on which your 2d array is mapped to matplotlib's `hexbin` function. You can make these grids in several ways, including writing your own function, but perhaps the best way is to just use `np.meshgrid`. Note that X, Y, and C parameters passed to the `hexbin` function all have to be 1d arrays.

```py
A = np.random.random((10, 10))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(A.shape[0]), range(A.shape[-1]))
X, Y = X*2, Y*2

# Turn this into a hexagonal grid
for i, k in enumerate(X):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        X[i] += 1
        Y[:,i] += 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.hexbin(
    X.reshape(-1), 
    Y.reshape(-1), 
    C=A.reshape(-1), 
    gridsize=int(A.shape[0]/2)
)

# the rest of the code is adjustable for best output
ax.set_aspect(0.8)
ax.set(xlim=(-4, X.max()+4,), ylim=(-4, Y.max()+4))
ax.axis(False)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your idea! But how to deal with the holes or seam

Comment: For this to work, you need to make a hexagonal grid. I have updated the answer to convert the meshgrid into a hexagonal one

Comment: Of course, if your grid is actually uniform, you should instead be using `ax.imshow`. But the above "trick" will work nonetheless.